# CORS issue between UI and couchDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, couchdb

I have CORS issue between UI and couchdb.
But in couchdb CORS is enabled, and UI has `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` header.
But I still have an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5984/cp_display_template/.
>   A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Someone has an idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure about this but try instead using `*` use `localhost:5984` in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. because for some security reason you can allow all requests. need to indicate specific domain