# Experiencing No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: couchdb

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and couchdb 1.6.1. I'm trying to sync a remote couchdb in my application but getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

I've done the following in couchdb local.ini file but still getting the errors

```
[httpd]
enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = *
```

Will really be helpful if this is resolve.
My app is running on `http://localhost:3000`
And the database host is `http://localhost:5984`

Comment: Could you try specifying a host as suggested in this other answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961783/cors-issue-between-ui-and-couchdb?rq=1

Comment: See [this readme](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb) to allow cors